# storyboard segue cross dissolve?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

**I want to use the following transition cross dissolve, but I do not want it to appear flicker when Transition**

I apologize I have weak English language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a subclass to your project:

- Add a new .h and .m file as a subclass of UIStoryboardSegue
- Add this code to your .m file:

`- (void)perform {
[self.sourceViewController presentModalViewController:self.destinationViewController
animated:NO];
}`

- Now go to your .storyboard and add the name of your .m file to the
  class field of your prefered segue.

Comment: Follow this tutorial: http://blog.jh-lim.com/2011/11/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-storyboard-segues/ --> instead of the code in this tutorial simply use the code I posted above.

Comment: Link above is broken. Please use this updated link: http://blog.jimjh.com/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-storyboard-segues.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the storyboard's segue's class field in XCode 4.4.1. Is it possible that the field was in previous versions but not in the current?

EDIT: I found the way. You must select 'custom' when creating the segue and it works.
Thanks.

BTW: The tutorial is not available.